# Xcode - Swift - iOS - Expanding TableView Cells Based on Title & Subtitle Sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview, cell

I have a TableView that uses custom cells. These custom cells have three labels in them. The UIViewController looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to make it so that depending on the length of the title, location, and time labels, the cell will expand accordingly. I have set the number of lines each of the labels can take up to 0 (infinite). The TableView itself is constrained to the sides and bottom of the ViewController, and on the top to the thin blue UIView. The constraints of the three labels within the cell are as follows:

"Title" label constraints:

[image: "Title" label constraints]

"Location" label constraints:

[image: "Location" label constraints]

"Time" label constraints:

[image: "Time" label constraints]

The problem is that when I run the simulator, I see that the labels, when the are too long for the cell, simply have "..." on the end, and don't go to the next line. They always stay one line. I want the text of the labels to go to next lines as needed and for the cell to expand accordingly.

In the code I have the lines:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
```

And I have the appropriate code the set the cells for the tableView, making sure to use the custom cell I have set up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the appropriate Content Compression Resistance Priority. This means that the label should try to resist "being squished" or compressed. Try making them slightly different for each label in case the constraints "compete" for some reason. For example, make the TitleLabel's vertical priority 752, LocationLabel 751, and TimeLabel 750.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I already have this to be 751, 750, and 749 for the title, location, and time labels respectively. Thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. After battling for ages I found that reducing the horizontal compression resistance settings for the labels to 250 (top label) and 251 (bottom label) worked!

I don't fully understand why, and have posted a question here to try find answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236691/how-does-reducing-horizontal-compression-resistance-for-a-label-affect-row-heigh

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you @VojtechVrbka Noted!